# what is the correct interpretation of precision, recall and F1 in R?

Tags: r, precision-recall, f1

Im using R and i had some cases of NAs for F1 when there is NA for precision and 0 for recall and also when both are 0, i also noticed that with both 0 i had f1 as Nan. So im not sure how to interpret that!

Answer (score 1):

As $F_1$ score is a ratio defined as $F_1 = \frac{2  \cdot\text{Prec} \cdot \text{Recall} }{\text{Prec}+ \text{Recall}}$. For the first case if Recall and Precision are 0 and `NA` respectively then 0 + `NA` is still `NA`, i.e. we get an $F_1$ that is `NA`. Similarly, if both Recall and Precision are 0 then we try compute $\frac{0}{0}$ so again that is not a valid number.